# String.Contains is returning False, When its True

Tags: c#, string, httpwebrequest, web-scraping, contains

I need this to be explained as for the love of god I dont know whats wrong.
I am downloading webpages via c#, standard Httpwebrequest.
I get the full HTML code and am saving it to a string.
I am then setting a webbrowsers data to it and when I click on elements, I get the Html such as:

```
<strong>Copyright 2011. All Rights Reserved.</strong>
```

When I get my script to compare the collection of pages downloaded for the existence of this exact string, I get false but If I open a single one of this collection in a RichTextBox, then start comparing the rest, It does match. Can anyone tell me why??
I have tried debugging and watching elements, nothing is ever null and even copying values to notepad to manually compare the text, I get a match every time so whats up?? Encoding? bug? I really dont know.

I get this example from: `http://web.archive.org/web/20110208042711/http://coralifeaqualight.com/`

The comparison pages are all the local pages on the site.
An answer here would be appreciated big time, it seems so simple, why wont it work?
And YES, I have tried putting an @ at the start when checking.

Comment: can you post your comparaison code please

Comment: Can you post some code? It would make it easier to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Could you post your script that is comparing the collection of pages downloaded?  There must be something in that script that is resulting in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Please post your code. It could be hidden characters or a case difference causing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Worst case scenario, you can try to get the same result without using Contains(). Here is an example.

```
string genericString = "My string";
bool contains = genericString.IndexOf("my", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if there are hidden characters that are interfering with matching in this way:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

...

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^\u0021-\u007E]","");
```

If they match after this, then you know there are some characters messing you up (line feed, maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that there is a character that is not displaying in the editor you are reviewing the data through. Try copying the exact data into something like TextPad and see if any extra characters are in the string.

That is the best I can do without code